# When authenticating with Facebook, how to prevent login to facebook.com

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, facebook-authentication

When authenticating a user account with firebase's facebook provider, the process automatically logs in the user to facebook.com as well.  How can I prevent this behavior?  My wish is to let the user authenticate on my web app by using facebook authentication **without** logging in the user to facebook.com.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use Facebook login with Firebase Authentication, you must sign the user in with Facebook. There is no way around it.

The best I can think of is to sign the user out of Facebook after they're sign in to Firebase. E.g. [`FB.logout()`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.logout/).

Comment: thank you for your reply...however, firebase uses a facebook provider object which doesn't include a method for signing out a user.  You sign out a user from firebase, by using the firebase.auth().signOut() method which doesn't include support for a Provider and signs the user from firebase, not any provider.

Comment: What platform are you using?

Comment: I'm using node with react/redux/webpack at the frontend. Server-side code is minimal. Everything happens client-side (1 page web app).

Comment: This call should work: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web/#logout But you'll indeed need to pull in the Facebook SDK for that. I'm afraid I don't know of another option.

Comment: yep, that'd do it alright...but I'm afraid that pulling the FB SDK while using firebase would be an overkill.  Let's see if anyone else knows how to achieve this ;-) thanks man!!